# How to append to url in React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-router

I want a way where the user clicks on a button and it will append e.g. `/completed` or `/active` to the url `http://localhost:3000/` so it becomes `http://localhost:3000/active` and then displays different content.

```
var router = Router({
                '/': ,
                '/active': ,
                '/completed': 
            });

router.init('/');
```

I guess I want something like the above but I'm not sure what would go after the different attributes?

I have had a little look at React-Router, but not sure if this is the best path to go down..

Any helps or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: What router  are you currently using? What is `Router()` in your code?

Comment: @David I am not using a Router at the moment. This was just some brief code that looked like it could by the foundation of what I need. Just not entirely sure which one to use and how to use it..

Comment: Use react-router, it'll do exactly what you wish for.

Comment: @limelights know any good tutorials?

Comment: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/docs